# Bounds for Poisson solution with Dirichlet B.C using Maximum Principle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, maximum-principle, poissons-equation

Let $U$ be a bounded, open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For any $u \in \mathcal{C}^2(\overline{U})$ show that $0\leq u \leq 1$ if it satisfies the Poisson problem with Dirichlet B.C. as 
\begin{equation}
\Delta u = f =u^{2k+1} \quad \text{in} \ U \quad \text{and} \quad u = 1 \quad \text{on} \ \partial U 
\end{equation}
and $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Now, I think I am stuck with this problem that it seemed to me simple but I cannot get my way through it properly (I just started studying PDE). Firstly I thought that I will use a subharmonic function such as the one produced using $\Delta v = \pm v^{2k}$ with same B.C. for which we obtain an upper bound such as $u \leq 1$. But I cannot properly justify that $\Delta u \leq \Delta v$ since $f$ changes sign. Then I proceeded with the more general approach, i.e. that
\begin{equation}
\max_{\overline{U}} |u| \leq C \max_{\overline{U}}|f| + \max_{\partial U} |g|
\end{equation}
with C a constant depending only on the domain $U$ and $g$ the value of $u$ at the boundary $\partial U$. For this case this translates to
\begin{equation}
\max_{\overline{U}} |u| \leq C \max_{\overline{U}}|u^{2k+1}| + 1
\end{equation}
But I don't know what to argue about the term $C \max_{\overline{U}}|u^{2k+1}|$, I was trying to think of a way to drive this to zero..

I am not asking for a solution but could you please provide me some hints or some guidelines for what I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: As a hint, try to show first that $u\geq 0$ in $U$, then you can use the maximum principle for subharmonic functions. The complete argument is written below.

Comment: @Hayk Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us show first that $u \geq 0$ in $U$. Assume, for contradiction that the set $\{x\in U:  u(x) < 0\}$ is not empty. Since $u \in C(\overline{U})$, $\overline{U}$ is compact (in view of boundedness of $U$), and $u>0$ in $\partial U$, it follows that $u$ attains a minimum in the interior of $U$, say at $x_0$. By our assumption, we get $u(x_0)<0$. Since $D^2 u(x_0)$ (the Hessian) must be positive definite at the point of minimum, we obtain 
$$0\leq \mathrm{tr}(D^2 u(x_0)) = \Delta u(x_0) = u^{2k+1}(x_0) < 0, 
$$
which is a contradiction (notice that we used the fact that $2k+1$ is odd, hence $u(x_0)<0$ implies $u^{2k+1}(x_0)<0$). Hence, $u\geq 0 $ everywhere in $U$.

But then, we have a subharmonic function at hand, i.e. $\Delta u  \geq 0$ everywhere in $U$, and the ordinary maximum principle implies that $u\leq \max_{\partial U} u =1 $ on $U$, completing the desired estimate.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you for the great explanation/answer, even though I asked just for a hint.

Comment: @ares, you're welcome!

Comment: I have a follow-up on this one. What if, instead of having the $f$ term being monotonic, you have an $f$ term that changes sign only once for $u < 0$ (or $u > 0$). Say $f=-1/u + u$ for $u \neq 0$ (same B.C., $u=1$ on $\partial U$). Something tells me that, again $u < 0$ is not possible because $u$ has to "come back" to reach the boundary value, but I don't know how to formally express this. Any hint?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by "$f$ changes sign once for $u<0$" (perhaps you can clarify), but we were using in a crucial way that $f$ preserved the sign of $u$ in the above argument. Even with everywhere positive $f$ the claim fails in general. For example, take $f = \alpha >0$ for some large constant $\alpha>0$ and consider the equation $\Delta u=f$ with boundary value $1$ in the unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then, $$u(x)=\frac{\alpha}{2d}(x_1^2+...+x_d^2)-\frac{\alpha}{2d}+1$$ solves the problem, but $u(0)<0$ for $\alpha>0$ large. So the sign-business with $f$ is crucial.

Comment: Yes, I didn't make it clear. The point is that there is a similar problem, with the only change being that $f(u) = -1/u + u$ instead of $f=u^{2k+1}$ and I want to show that $u \equiv 1$ is the only solution. Now I saw that $f$ changes sign at $\pm 1$. The claim that we used about the Hessian cannot be used anymore. I am trying to figure out how to prove that this is not possible and that the only admissible solution must be $u \equiv 1$.

Comment: @ares, with $f=-1/u+u$ the approach of the solution works. Indeed, since you have $C^2$ solutions, then $u\neq 0$ in $\Omega$ because of the $-1/u$ term. Thus we have $u$ preserving the sign in $\Omega$, hence $u>0$ in $\Omega$ thanks to the boundary condition. If $u\geq 1$ everywhere in $\Omega$ then we get $ \Delta u \geq 0$ and hence max. principle implies $u\leq 1$ and thus $u=1$ in $\Omega$. Otherwise, if there is a point $x_0\in \Omega$ with $u(x_0)<1$ then at the point of min. of $u$ the exact same argument as above gives the contradiction, since at points of $u<1$ we have $\Delta u<0$.

Comment: I fully understand the second part of the explanation but I don't understand how from saying that $u \neq 0$ you say that $u$ is preserving the sign in $\Omega$ and thus $u >0$ in $\Omega$. Why should $u$ preserve the sign? It is changing sign at $\pm 1$. This is the precise point that I am missing.

Comment: we have $u\in C^2(\overline{U})$ impliying that $|\Delta u|$ is bounded in $\overline{U}$. Now assume $u$ changes sign in $U$. Since $u$ is continuous, it must attain $0$ value (intermediate value theorem). In a neighborhood of a point $x$ where $u(x) = 0$ the term $-1/u(x)$ is not bounded, hence $\Delta u$ is not bounded as well as it equals $-1/u + u$. But this is a contradiction (see the 1st sentence). Thus $u$ cannot change sign in $U$. Now, $u=1 $ on $\partial U$, in particular it must become positive (by continuity) when you approach $\partial U$. Hence, $u>0$ everywhere in $U$.